# Polymorphic associations or belongs_to associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I am using polymorphic associations in this case:

```
class Adress < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :addresses, as: :addressable
end
```

What I want now is a User to have a home address and a work address.
I could have:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :home_address, as: :addressable
  has_one :work_address, as: :addressable
end
```

But then I would not know which one is the home address and which one is the work address.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have an `Addresses` table, keep one field as '`addressable_type`' in your `Addresses` table. Than you will be able to identify different addresses.

Either you can have these fields in your address table,

```
t.integer :addressable_id
t.string  :addressable_type
```

or Simplified version :

```
t.references :addressable, polymorphic: true
```

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but the addressable_type doesn't help me, because what it saves is the class "User". Anyway, thank you for your help.

Comment: addressable_type is the standard name of the field which stores the class of the associated object in a polymorphic relationship.  You should add another field, called "category" or something, which can store "Work", "Home", "Mobile" etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could set up STI. You'll need to create a `type` column in your Address model.

```
class Adress < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class WorkAddress < Address
   belongs_to :user
end

class HomeAddress < Address
   belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :work_address
  has_one :home_address
end
```

Comment: Seems to me like a very good solution. I will try it. Thanks mate :)

Comment: @GustavoLobo No problem. If this is the answer that works for you then please accept it as correct. Many thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work, because what it actually saves on the table Address is the class User. Anyway, thank you :)

Comment: @GustavoLobo - Hi, if STI is set up correctly it would save the class name `WorkAddress` or `HomeAddress` in the `type` column of the `Address` table. If you want to chat any further, we can in chat :)